# Строка (string) состоит из байтов, как извлечь из нее байты

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, numpy

Есть строка `use[1] = "строка \n string".encode('utf-8')` перевожу в байт код и помещаю ее в таблицу Pandas и сохраняю таблицу в csv. В байт код для того чтобы можно было в дальнейшем извлечь строку так как она содержит \n знак переноса на новую строку. Если оставить с этим знаком то таблица в дальнейшем не читается. 
далее читаю таблицу`train_dataset = np.genfromtxt('data', usecols=use[1:4], delimiter=';',dtype=object,skip_header=1)`. Данные перевожу из байт кода в utf-8  и у меня получилась строка из байтов тип String но там перечислены байты.

```
for x in range(train_dataset.shape[0]):
   train_dataset[x][0]=train_dataset[x][0].decode('utf-8')
   train_dataset[x][1] = train_dataset[x][1].decode('utf-8')
   train_dataset[x][2] = train_dataset[x][2].decode('utf-8')
print(train_dataset)
```

`"b'\\xd1\\x81\\xd1\\x82\\xd1\\x80\\xd0\\xbe\\xd0\\xba\\xd0\\xb0 \\n \\xd1\\x81\\xd1\\x82\\xd1\\x80\\xd0\\xb8\\xd0\\xbd\\xd0\\xb3'"` результат это тип стринг, как перевести в тип byte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не надо ничего выдумывать - Pandas замечательно справляется с переносами строк:

```
In [22]: df = pd.DataFrame({
    ...:   'id': [1,2,3],
    ...:   'text': ['aaa', 'xxx\nyyy\nzzz', 'ccc'],
    ...:   'val': [10,20,30]
    ...: })

In [23]: df
Out[23]:
   id           text  val
0   1            aaa   10
1   2  xxx\nyyy\nzzz   20
2   3            ccc   30

In [24]: print(df.loc[1, 'text'])
xxx
yyy
zzz

In [25]: df.to_csv('c:/temp/1.csv', index=False)

In [26]: pd.read_csv('c:/temp/1.csv')
Out[26]:
   id           text  val
0   1            aaa   10
1   2  xxx\nyyy\nzzz   20
2   3            ccc   30
```

CSV файл - обратите внимание на то что строка с переносами строк заключена в двойные кавычки, иначе такой файл не будет являться корректным CSV файлом:

```
id,text,val
1,aaa,10
2,"xxx
yyy
zzz",20
3,ccc,30
```

---

**UPDATE:** как прочитать CSV файл в Numpy NDArray:

воспользуйтесь атрибутом `DataFrame.values`:

```
In [43]: pd.read_csv('c:/temp/1.csv').values
Out[43]:
array([[1, 'aaa', 10],
       [2, 'xxx\nyyy\nzzz', 20],
       [3, 'ccc', 30]], dtype=object)
```

начиная с версии 0.24.0 в Pandas существует метод [DataFrame.to_numpy()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html):

```
In [44]: pd.read_csv('c:/temp/1.csv').to_numpy()
Out[44]:
array([[1, 'aaa', 10],
       [2, 'xxx\nyyy\nzzz', 20],
       [3, 'ccc', 30]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Вы используете таблицу Pandas для сохранения и загрузки, а мне нужно загрузить не таблицу Pandas, а из csv файла в массив numpy. Для сохранения в csv использую Pandas. У меня получилось это сделать заменив \n на другой знак с помощью метода replace, но вопрос остался не решенным, как из строки в которой содержаться байты(строка типа String) получить байты(Тип byte). Извините. Спасибо за ответ

Comment: @Alexandr1234567890, именно это я и делаю в конце ответа - последняя строка кода

Comment: метод pd.read(file) возвращает DataFrame, а нужен массив numpy

Comment: @Alexandr1234567890, дополнил ответ...

Comment: @Alexandr1234567890, можете выложить пример CSV, позволяющий воспроизвести проблему, на какой-нибудь файлообменник?

Comment: извините это видимо разделитель не указан. Обновил pandas  появился метод to_numpy все заработало